# Issue with cross-referencing and augmenting XML elements in XSLT using document()

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm a bit of a newbie to XML and I have a problem where I have an XML document which has been generated for which the attribute list for some elements is incomplete. I am trying to implement an XSLT stylesheet which cross-references it with a master document (which is complete with default values for all attributes) in order to populate any missing attributes with default values.

For example, take the following incomplete XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
  <bar label="two" index="2"/>
</foo>
```

The bar element has a missing attribute 'type' which I would like to populate with a default value from the following master document according to the value of 'label':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
  <bar label="one" index="1" type="type1"/>
  <bar label="two" index="2" type="type2"/>
  <bar label="three" index="3" type="type3"/>
</foo>
```

The desired result would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
  <bar label="two" index="2" type="type2"/>
</foo>
```

My XSLT stylesheet attempts to do this using a combination of 'document()' and XPath as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:variable name="master" select="document('master.xml')"/>

  <!-- Template matching 'root' of XML document -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="foo"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Template for generating 'foo' element -->
  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <foo>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="bar"/>
    </foo>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Template for generating 'bar' element -->
  <xsl:template match="bar">
    <bar label="{@label}" index="{@index}" type="{$master/foo/bar[@label=@label][1]/@type}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This however does not work and gives me the default 'type' attribute for the 'bar' element with 'label' of 'one' rather than 'two':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
  <bar label="two" index="2" type="type1"/>
</foo>
```

Some investigation has revealed that the XPath pattern is matching all the 'bar' elements rather than just the correct one but I'm not sure why.

What am I doing wrong and is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: This seems to be always true [@label=@label]. Did you want [@label=current()/@label] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem is in this line**:

```
<bar label="{@label}" index="{@index}" 
     type="{$master/foo/bar[@label=@label][1]/@type}"/>
```

You are essentially checking if the `label` attribute of a `bar` element is equal to itself -- and this is equivalent to:

```
<bar label="{@label}" index="{@index}" 
     type="{$master/foo/bar[true()][2]/@type}"/>
```

**and this is equivalent to**:

```
<bar label="{@label}" index="{@index}" 
     type="{$master/foo/bar[1]/@type}"/>
```

This is how the results you observe are produced.

**Solution**: Use the XSLT **[`current()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current)** function:

```
<bar label="{@label}" index="{@index}" 
     type="{$master/foo/bar[@label=current()/@label][4]/@type}"/>
```

**The complete transformation becomes** (I have changed the URL to `master.xml` to be able to run the transformation on my local computer):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

      <xsl:variable name="master" select=
      "document('file:///c:/temp/delete/master.xml')"/>

      <!-- Template matching 'root' of XML document -->
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="foo"/>
      </xsl:template>

      <!-- Template for generating 'foo' element -->
      <xsl:template match="foo">
        <foo>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="bar"/>
        </foo>
      </xsl:template>

      <!-- Template for generating 'bar' element -->
      <xsl:template match="bar">
        <bar label="{@label}" index="{@index}"
        type="{$master/foo/bar[@label=current()/@label][5]/@type}"/>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<foo>
    <bar label="two" index="2"/>
</foo>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<foo><bar label="two" index="2" type="type2"/></foo>
```

---

**II. Potentially more efficient solution, using [keys](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kTypeByLabel" match="@type" use="../@label"/>

      <xsl:variable name="master" select=
      "document('file:///c:/temp/delete/master.xml')"/>

      <!-- Template matching 'root' of XML document -->
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="foo"/>
      </xsl:template>

      <!-- Template for generating 'foo' element -->
      <xsl:template match="foo">
        <foo>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="bar"/>
        </foo>
      </xsl:template>

      <!-- Template for generating 'bar' element -->
      <xsl:template match="bar">
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="vDefault">
          <xsl:for-each select="$master">
            <xsl:value-of select=
                "key('kTypeByLabel', $vCurrent/@label)"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <bar label="{@label}" index="{@index}" type="{$vDefault}"/>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the (same) provided XML document (above), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<foo>
   <bar label="two" index="2" type="type2"/>
</foo>
```

Comment: Indeed, adding 'current()' solves my issue. Context is one of the things I struggle to get my head around with XSLT, especially when trying to reference information from more than one location. Thanks for your help. It's much appreciated! Thanks also for the alternative solution which looks interesting.